# How can I get a sinqle sql query to check if a record has existed throughout a predefined period?

Tags: sql

I would like to have your assistance with a query\task in which, given a date and an integer value,
I need to check how much items exist(ed) at a particular location for that date, and then retroactively the 1 month prior based on the integer value.

For example, the table "Items" is structed as such:

| ItemID | ItemName | Loaction | DateAdded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ChairA | Loc1 | 2022-04-15 |
| 2 | ChairB | Loc2 | 2022-04-17 |
| 3 | ChairC | Loc1 | 2022-05-23 |
| 4 | ChairD | Loc3 | 2022-06-25 |

given the date: 2022-06-30, and an integer value of 3 (for months to check)
the result I'm looking for is something like:

| MonthEnd | Location | Items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-30 | Loc1 | 2 |
| 2022-06-30 | Loc2 | 1 |
| 2022-06-30 | Loc3 | 1 |
| 2022-05-31 | Loc1 | 2 |
| 2022-05-31 | Loc2 | 1 |
| 2022-05-31 | Loc3 | 0 |
| 2022-04-31 | Loc1 | 1 |
| 2022-04-31 | Loc2 | 1 |
| 2022-04-31 | Loc3 | 0 |

I can do the single month checks individually by doing

```sql
select location, count(*) 
from Items 
where DateAdded <= @CurrentMonth 
group by location
```

but wanted to know if there is a way for the query to continue to check the number of previous months
the user indicates (which can range from 0 to 12) without doing a bunch of unions

your assistance would be highly welcome.

Comment: You need to outer-join with a calendar table or a generated sequence of dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operations such as generating series and date functions are very system specific, here are examples how to do it in Oracle and SQL Server:

```
select location, eomonth('2022-06-30', -value) dt, 
       count(case when dateadded <= eomonth('2022-06-30', -value) then 1 end) cnt  
  from items cross join generate_series(0, 2)   
  group by location, eomonth('2022-06-30', -value);
```

[dbfiddle demo for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/yZTeuVSa)

```
select location, dt, count(case when dateadded <= dt then 1 end) cnt 
  from items
  cross join (select add_months(last_day(date '2022-06-30'), - level + 1) dt
              from dual connect by level <= 3)
  group by location, dt
```

[dbfiddle demo for Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2BDgEwti)

Method is similar, join items with auto generated rows, find last day of month, count rows conditionally.